# pro micro timers and controlled pins datasheet

Tags: microcontroller

I am using a Pro Micro with a ATMega32U4, where can I find timer number and which pins that controlled?

I just found Arduino Mega: (tested on Arduino Mega 2560)
timer 0 (controls pin 13, 4)
timer 1 (controls pin 12, 11)
timer 2 (controls pin 10, 9)
timer 3 (controls pin 5, 3, 2)
timer 4 (controls pin 8, 7, 6)

Can I use this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the datasheet ATMega32U4 has four timers:

- Timer0 controls pin functions OC0A, OC0B
- Timer1 controls pin functions OC1A, OC1B, OC1C
- Timer3 controls pin functions OC3A
- Timer4 controls pin functions OC4A, OC4B, OC4D and inverted !OC4A, !OC4B, !OC4D

Pin functions are multiplexed on physical pins. E.g. OC0A and OC1C are multiplexed on pin 12 (PB7). So those pin functions should not be used at the same time. You need to choose which one you want to use. See the [Pin Configurations](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-7766-8-bit-avr-atmega16u4-32u4_datasheet.pdf#G1.1030867) chapter for more details.

Comment: Thank you user930473, seems the pro micro's timer don't have specific pin signed to a timer like Mega 2560 does?

Comment: ATmega32U4 does have specific pins connected to timers. Some pins are connected to multiple timers. If you are referring to Sparkfun product 12640, then this board does not have all the pins of ATmega32U4 routed to JP6 and JP7 connectors. However some pins are routed, e.g. Timer1's OC1A is routed to JP7 pin 1 and OC1B is routed to JP6 pin 12. See board schematics for more details: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Boards/Pro_Micro_v13b.pdf